# LogStash::ConfigurationError but Configuration OK

Tags: logstash

I verified Logstash config:

```
root@learn-elk:/etc/logstash/conf.d# /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -t /etc/logstash/conf.d/
Configuration OK
```

but still getting error and pipeline aborted after

```
==> /var/log/logstash/logstash.log <==
{:timestamp=>"2016-10-22T17:48:28.391000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline aborted due to error", :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:88:in `config_init'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:72:in `config_init'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:79:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:74:in `register'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181:in `start_workers'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181:in `start_workers'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:491:in `start_pipeline'"], :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2016-10-22T17:48:31.424000+0000", :message=>"stopping pipeline", :id=>"main"}
```

after running logstash with '-v --debug --verbose' I've got much more information:

```
starting agent {:level=>:info}
starting pipeline {:id=>"main", :level=>:info}
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 1
Registering file input {:path=>["/opt/logstash/GOOG.csv"], :level=>:info}
No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the file path {:sincedb_path=>"/root/.sincedb_0a3b7d0b4841f166ec450717c6ce4124", :path=>["/opt/logstash/GOOG.csv"], :level=>:info}
Pipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:88:in `config_init'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:72:in `config_init'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:79:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:74:in `register'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181:in `start_workers'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181:in `start_workers'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:491:in `start_pipeline'"], :level=>:error}
stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
Closing inputs {:level=>:info}
Closed inputs {:level=>:info}
```

After fixing logstash { hosts => ["localhost"] } } vs { host => localhost } } issue I consolidated config into one file below and used stdout instead elasticsearch

```
input{
file{
path =>"/opt/logstash/GOOG.csv"
start_position =>"beginning"
type => google
}
}
filter{
if [type] == "google" {
csv{
columns =>
["date_of_record","open","high","low","close","volume","adj_close"]
separator => ","
}
date {
match => ["date_of_record","yyyy-MM-dd"]
}
mutate {
convert => ["open","float"]
convert => ["high","float"]
convert => ["low","float"]
convert => ["close","float"]
convert => ["volume","integer"]
convert => ["adj_close","float"]
}
}
output {
  stdout {
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a lot of details in the stack trace.  Try starting with ---verbose or --debug?

Comment: question updated with debug, thnx

Comment: After changing output from elasticsearch {host => "localhost"} to elasticsearch {hosts => ["localhost"]} logstash is up and running, no error;) But still no index created in elasticsearch so I have to review input and filter..in fact it is taken from book https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-elk-stack/9781785887154/ch02s04.html

Comment: If you could show us your conf file?